# How to select the nodes in a embedded svg-graphic?

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I want to work with the nodes of a pre-created svg image with the jquery svg plugin. With this plugin it is possible to create and edit the nodes but i can't handle the existing ones. the selectors doesn't find the nodes, which are defined in the svg image.

f.e. i must select it via its id, like:

```
$("#svg_image>#node_rectangle_1")
```

Comment: Your problem relates to SVG namespace and jQuery. (Search for these terms.) I mostly never use jQuery with SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match SVG elements with id selectors. You should use the [getElementById()](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html#getelementbyid) method provided by the plugin instead:

```
var svg = $("#svg_image").svg("get");
var node_rect = svg.getElementById("node_rectangle_1");
```

Comment: Since when (which version of FF) is node.getElementById supported?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your comment: the `getElementById()` method is provided by the SVG plugin, not the browser.